# Should I use aria-controls with aria-labelledby in bootstrap tabs?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, wai-aria

I have been reading about bootstrap tabs from their [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage). The markup suggested is as:

```
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

On tabpanels bootstrap doesn't use `aria-labelledby` attribute. but [here](http://accessibility.athena-ict.com/aria/examples/tabpanel2.shtml) in the step 2 they are using `aria-labelledby` on `tabpanel`. So my question is:

- Should I use aria-controls with aria-labelledby in bootstrap tabs for making it better for screen readers?

Comment: Here’s a tutorial on how to implement accessible tabs with ARIA: https://hackpoets.wordpress.com/2016/05/10/from-html-to-aria-tabs-a-travelog/

Comment: @ŠimeVidas In that link they are not using `aria-controls` but are using `aria-labelledby`. So does it mean only one of them is required? Shouldn't I use them together?

Comment: They're using both attributes; see (and inspect) the demo: http://a11yideas.com/testcode/tabs/tabs_with_ARIA.html; this is state-of-the-art ARIA tabs :)

Comment: Take a look at this post for some additional info/opinions on `aria-controls`: http://www.heydonworks.com/article/aria-controls-is-poop and then pay attention to the comments.

Comment: @aardrian So at present no screen readers implement correctly aria :-/ But at least it helps keyboard navigation of website.

Comment: On the contrary, most screen readers support quite a lot of ARIA and have done so for many years. `aria-controls` was, I suspect, a lower priority because it does not provide a bi-directional mapping in most cases. Also, ARIA itself does little for keyboard navigation. That is handled with good HTML and some add-on JavaScript as necessary. Just adding `role="tabpanel"` does not make it work with a keyboard. You have to add all the key bindings yourself. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#tabpanel